# click event inside ngFor does Not work Angular 7

Tags: angular7, angular-reactive-forms, ngfor

I am having the following Piece of Code:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" *ngFor="let airline of airlines">
                      <input type="checkbox" (click)="airLineFilter($event)" value="{{airline}}" name="{{airline}}" class="custom-control-input">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{airline}}">{{airline}}</label>
                    </div>
```

When this was without `*ngFor` `(click)` event was working fine like this:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="americanAir" (click)="airLineFilter($event)" value="American Airlines" name="airlines" class="custom-control-input">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="americanAir">American Airlines</label>
                </div>
```

But after using `*ngFor` click event is not getting triggered. Is there something I can do to fix this.?

Comment: I run your code and its working for me.

Comment: Could you please say whats the exact issue you are facing and please attach a screenshot of error if any?

Comment: No there are no errors in that. After inspecting element I figured it out that due some reason `Label` is overlapping with checkbox, which is not visible on UI.

Comment: May be it will be due to the style issues.Please check the style class you have used

Comment: I have the similar problem :(

Answer (score 0):

After going through many options I finally found the solution.
It is due to **Id** attribute of checkbox and **for** attribute of label.

When I changed my code to something like this it worked:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" *ngFor="let airline of airlines;let i = $index;">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="airline{{i}}" (click)="airLineFilter($event)" value="{{airline}}" name="{{airline}}" class="custom-control-input">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="airline{{i}}">{{airline}}</label>
                </div>
```